# Exception nette-ajax extension error in IE8

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8, nette

I have a problem with an exception nette-ajax extension in IE8. Does anybody know, what does it mean and how fix it?

[image: Screenshot of the exception]

Comment: Please provide code sample and include error in the question. [SO how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: seems that you are loading nette.ajax.js or some of its extensions twice, read the error message in browser :)

btw, does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ext = function (name, callbacks, context) {
    if (typeof name === 'object') {
        inner.ext(name, callbacks);
    } else if (callbacks === undefined) {
        return inner.contexts[name];
    } else if (!callbacks) {
        $.each(['init', 'load', 'prepare', 'before', 'start', 'success', 'complete', 'error'], function (index, event) {
            inner.on[event][name] = undefined;
        });
        inner.contexts[name] = undefined;
    } else if (typeof name === 'string' && inner.contexts[name] !== undefined) {
        throw "Cannot override already registered nette-ajax extension '" + name + "'.";
    } else {
        inner.ext(callbacks, context, name);
    }
    return this;
};
```

in console.log(name) is result redirect